# Can't get custom controller's records on a vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I'am trying to create a custom controller that will find the contacts from the opportunity contact role and will print them out on a visualforce page along with some custom fields from the contact object itself.

The issue is that there are no results. I've tried the same approach with a standardcontroller + extension but still couldn't spill out the contents from the last list.

The vf page is a test page that i'am using to see whether I can print out any values.

## Apex Class:

```
public class controller_getcontactroleinfo {
public List<Contact> contactList {get;set;}
public List<OpportunityContactRole> croles {get;set;}
public String currentRecordId {get;set;}
public List<Contact> conts {get;set;}
public List<Id> ls {get;set;}

private String oppID;
public String OpportunityID {
    get {
        if(oppID != NULL && oppID != '') {
            return oppID;
        }
        else {
            return Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
        }
    }
    set {
        oppID = value;
    }
}


public controller_getcontactroleinfo() {
    system.debug('controller_getcontactroleinfo-constructor');
    contactList = new List<Contact>();
    croles = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
    currentRecordId = '';
    conts = new List<Contact>();
    ls = new List<Id>();
}

public List<Contact> getContacts(){
    croles = [SELECT ContactId FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE OpportunityId = OpportunityID];

    for (OpportunityContactRole ocr : croles){
        ls.add(ocr.ContactId);
    }

    conts = [SELECT Id,Name,Email,Last_Login__c,Early_Payment_Count_Taken_One_Year_co__c  FROM Contact WHERE Id In :ls];

    return conts;
}


}
```

## VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="controller_getcontactroleinfo">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail" id="ContactId">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!conts}" var="c">
            <apex:column headerValue="Contact Name">
                <apex:outputLink value="/{!c.Id}"></apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>

        <apex:outputText style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px;" value="THERE ARE NO RECORDS TO DISPLAY!"> </apex:outputText>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Are you sure there's actually data?

Comment: There is data, the contact roles on the opportunity were there. I've also did a system debug to check if the page was pulling the opportunity id correctly - it was.

Comment: `Seems, you need to bind "contacts" instead of "conts" on VF page.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I can finally see that there is a query in the debug log.

Comment: If you're new to visualforce development, try the [Visualforce Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/module/visualforce_fundamentals) to get accustomed to the development enviroment.

Comment: If this was a matter of a typo, please delete.